# Update query in mysqli function using object oriented php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am doing work with php object oriented and mysqli. i have class name Database.php inside this class i have defined a function name update.
i did some thing wrong i think that's why it doesn't work fine. when i use to run click at update then data retrieves in Form but when i try to save the updated form it always updated only first column of my database. function code is given below:

```
    public function update($tablename, $value, $where){
    $Update = " UPDATE ".$tablename." SET ";
    $array_keys = array_keys($value);
    $array_values= array_values($value);
    $count = count($array_keys);
    for($i=0; $i< $count; $i++){
        $value[$i] = " = '".$value[$array_keys[$i]]."' ";
    }
       //$value = implode(" ",$value);
    print_r($value);
  $Update .= " ".$value." WHERE ".$where;

    $Utest = $this->DbCon->query($Update);
    if($Utest){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

here is php code that i have tried before

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $id1 =  $_POST['id'];
    $name =  $_POST['name'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $success=$DbQuery->update("record", array(" name " => $name ,"city" => $city)," id =".$id1);
    if($success){
       header("LOCATION:index.php");
    }else{
        echo "try again ";
    }

}
```

do you have any good suggestion for update function how ic an improve this function. actually i am new in php object oriented so suggest me easy method to this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to convert the `$value` array to a string in `$Update .= " ".$value." WHERE ".$where;`. You can't do that. You have to construct the query in the for loop above it instead of populating the `$value` array. Either way you shouldn't be building the query by hand. You REALLY should use `PDO::prepare()` or `$mysqli::prepare()` to prevent vulnerabilities. Yes, that might feel like an overkill if you're just learning, but you should start forming good habits from the very beginning.

Also, fix your formatting. Your code is really hard to read. I recommend reading through the [PSR standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) (or any widespread PHP standard) and adapting it in your code. Again, might feel like overkill, but it's a good habit to pick up early.

Here's an [adapted version of your code](http://runnable.com/VXMpCLQIwo9jqJqH/so-30685053-for-php) for you to easily play with. You can see the problem if you run `php index.php` in the CLI window at the bottom.